# Issues when trying to line up divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack some long and shorter divs in a table-esque layout so that the div borders line up & create a grid.

Here is the basics of what I am doing on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wFjXD/

I am having a couple issues:

1) Why is there a gap between my longer divs ?

2) If the gap goes away, the divs will be aligned, but if I zoom in or out on the page with ctrl + or ctrl - , the alignment will get off. How can I hardcode the long div to always have the same width of 5 smaller divs no matter the zoom level.

Thanks!

Comment: The gap was due to the white space between the divs. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wFjXD/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hi now give to `font size 0` in **parent** and give another **font size in your child**

as like this

```
.cellcontainer {
font-size:0;
}
.longcell {
font-size:15px;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wFjXD/3/)***